# JS function breaks upon entering no argument

Tags: javascript, function

Here is a simple function, that counts the price of engraving, based on the entered phrase length.

```
function engravePrice(phraseToEngrave) {

  var pricePerWord = 11;
  var wordsToEngrave = phraseToEngrave.split(' ');

  if (phraseToEngrave.length === 0){
    return 0;
  } else if (phraseToEngrave.length > 0){
    return wordsToEngrave.length * pricePerWord;
  }
}

console.log(`Gift wrap and engraving price is: ${engravePrice('')} Q`);
```

It actually works pretty well:

```
engravePrice('Two words') //will return 22, as expected
engravePrice('') //will return 0, as expected
```

except for one specific situation:

```
engravePrice() //when it breaks, saying "cannot read property 'split' of undefined"
```

Is there a solution for that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want it to do when there’s no input?

Comment: If it should return the same as empty string, just do `phraseToEngrave = phraseToEngrave || '';` as the first line of your function.

Comment: or `engravePrice(phraseToEngrave='')`

Comment: use if statement at the beginning of function with `typeof phraseToEngrave =="undefined"`  and do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `phraseToEngrave`.for undefined, e.g.

```
function engravePrice(phraseToEngrave) {
if (!phraseToEngrave) return 0;
...
}
```

or in ES6, give it a default:

```
   function engravePrice(phraseToEngrave = '') {
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
function engravePrice(phraseToEngrave) {
  var phraseToEngrave = phraseToEngrave || '';
  var pricePerWord = 11;
  var wordsToEngrave = phraseToEngrave.split(' ');

  if (phraseToEngrave.length === 0){
    return 0;
  } else if (phraseToEngrave.length > 0){
    return wordsToEngrave.length * pricePerWord;
  }
}
```

Which just converts it to an empty string if nothing is passed.